Classification based on two attributes in QGIS
I am using QGIS occasionally to illustrate landscape analyses, assessments and resources. Nothing too fancy at this stage.
I have been wondering how I can classify my map based on two attributes.
In this example, I want to classify my landscape types based on their character type - let's say into 7 classes (7 colours). At the same time, I want to classify those landscapes based on their detailed character zones - each being a shade of the colour from the higher tier class (character type).
So, for example, where I have the rural landscape type coloured in yellow, I want fields, margins, pasture etc coloured in different shades of yellow. I can't figure out how to do it or how to code it in Expression Builder.
Any suggestions?

Have you tried with Rule based styling? You have an attribute for type, and another for character zone?

Have a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191146/how-to-use-nested-styles-in-qgis
